# Problem using simple_permissions in my project ios & android

Tags: ios, flutter

Im getting this error, when i added package to pubspec.yaml

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 7 Plus in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            2.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET url_launcher OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/zimbronapps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/ios/Classes/SimplePermissionsPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'simple_permissions/simple_permissions-Swift.h' file not found
```

I need to use simple_permission for android version

pubspec.yaml in the next code box, i need to write more text, because i cant add it jeje, can some one help me pleasE?

```
name: myapp
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  launch_review: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^5.0.1
  share: ^0.6.0+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.0
  flutter_sound: ^1.3.1
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  permission: ^0.1.1 
  audioplayers: ^0.8.1
  firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
   - ./assets/drawable/
   - ./assets/raw/
```

this is my pubspec.yaml

Comment: could you add your pubspec.yml file ?

Comment: @diegoveloper added

Comment: try using this package : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions

Answer (score 1):

try this

Edit your Podfile

Add or uncomment after "target 'Runner' do" line number ~35

```
use_frameworks!
```

Then add this line after line number ~67

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
```

Example:

```
target 'Runner' do
  ** use_frameworks!  **
```

........
......

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
        end
      end
    end
```

delete your Podfile.lock and try. Good luck